# KafkaMessageListenerContainer reprocess a message if there is servicedown exception

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We want to have a Spring Kafka listener configured in such a way that if any external service is down we don't want to loose the message that's consumed from Kafka. we want to revert it back till it is successfully processed.

could you please help with the configuration that I can use to achieve the same.

How can I handle it if I consume the message in batches.

We are using Kafka 0.9

Answer (score 1):

I think [Retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_retrying_deliveries) best fits to your requirements:

> To retry deliveries, convenient listener adapters - `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter` and `RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter` are provided, depending on whether you are using a `MessageListener` or an `AcknowledgingMessageListener`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, could you please let us know is there a way we can achieve this using Spring-Kafka 1.0.0 Release

Comment: But that functionality exists there exactly since `1.0.0.RC1`. Not sure in your concern...