# Consume same record after manual commit failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a `KafkaConsumer` which consumes messages, does some processing and then a `KafkaProducer` sends message to another topic. I am currently manually committing the offset using `Acknowledge.acknowledge()` when `KafkaProducer` successfully sends message to another topic, but I do not call `Acknowledge.acknowledge()` when message fails to send. I have set `ackMode` to `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`

However when I do not commit the offset manually, `KafkaConsumer` should pick the same record that failed to process (i.e failed to send to another topic) but even on failure the offset is incremented and the next record is processed. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? And how can I achieve this?

**KafkaConsumer.java**

```
@Autowired
private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;    

@KafkaListener(id = "workerListener", topics = "${kafka.topic.name}",
        containerFactory = "workerKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void workerListener(ConsumerRecord<?,?> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {

    // Do something! Process consumer record

    // Now producer will send to another topic
    kafkaProducer.sendNotification(notification, ack);
}
```

**KafkaProducer.java**

```
...
...

public void sendNotification(String notification, Acknowledgment ack) {

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = 
            notificationKafkaTemplate.send(topicName, String);

    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
            handleNotificationSuccess();
            ack.acknowledge();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            handleNotificationFailure(ex);
        }

    });
}

public void handleNotificationSuccess() {
    // handle notification success
}

public void handleNotificationFailure(Throwable ex) {
    // handle notification failure
}
```

Please tell me if any more information is required. Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

I started implementing [Seeking to a Specific Offset](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#seek) but encountered a problem. Here is the code:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    private final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @KafkaListener(id = "workerListener", topics = "${kafka.topic.name}",
        containerFactory = "workerKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void workerListener(ConsumerRecord<?,?> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {

        this.seekCallBack().get().seek(consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.partition(), 0);

        // Now producer will send to another topic
        kafkaProducer.sendNotification(notification, ack);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        this.seekCallBack.set(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback csc) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback csc) {
    }

}
```

I don't seem to understand what the problem is. Here is the stack trace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-04 23:15:18,670 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaConsumer' defined in class path resource [com/tgss/mdm/worker/consumer/kafkaods/config/AppConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @KafkaListener method 'workerListener' found on bean target class 'KafkaConsumer', but not found in any interface(s) for bean JDK proxy. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass attribute to 'true'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.tgss.mdm.worker.consumer.kafkaods.KafkaApplication.main(KafkaApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @KafkaListener method 'workerListener' found on bean target class 'KafkaConsumer', but not found in any interface(s) for bean JDK proxy. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass attribute to 'true'
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.checkProxy(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processKafkaListener(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.workerListener(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.checkProxy(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are looking for logic for retrying the processing of failed records. am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Just to be clear, failed processing means that the producer failed to send the message to the topic and now this record needs to be consumed again

Comment: I hope you can use Retry logic. as already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346179/kafkamessagelistenercontainer-reprocess-a-message-if-there-is-servicedown-except

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Would it be better to use Seeking to a Specific Offset like so https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#seek.

Comment: Either way. What is convenient for you.

Comment: You can also throw an exception and use the new `Seek To Current` error handlers in 2.1.0 [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_seek_to_current_container_error_handlers).

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response. I started to implement `Seeking to a Specific Offset` but ran into a problem. Please see my edit. Would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @KafkaListener method 'workerListener' found on bean target class 'KafkaConsumer', but not found in any interface(s) for bean JDK proxy. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass attribute to 'true'
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.checkProxy(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processKafkaListener(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.workerListener(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)
```

I would suggest to follow recommendations: or use CGLIB `proxyTargetClass = true`, or extract an interface with an appropriate method to let the JDK Proxy to work properly.

Comment: Solved it by adding `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` in the `application.properties` file. Thanks